# EXIM4 configuration directives: .ifdef, ifndef

Tags: configuration, exim

all!

I'm configuring exim mail-server and I'm a newbie to it. It is not my first mail server configuration, but first of exim.

So far, I have read different config docs (e.g. [this one](http://marc.merlins.org/linux/exim/)) in the Internet and an exim's configuration manual, as well. And now it is more clear to me. But one issue is not clear yet - it is concerned  `.ifdef, .ifndef`  directives.
For example,

```
.ifdef CHECK_MAIL_HELO_ISSUED
  deny
    message = no HELO given before MAIL command
    condition = ${if def:sender_helo_name {no}{yes}}
.endif
```

As far as I saw from the [manual](http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_run_time_configuration_file.html), this clause means if the macros CHECK_MAIL_HELO_ISSUED is declared, then followed actions will be applied. But if it is not present anywhere, the actions will not be applied.
And if I want to apply that acl (it is a part of acl), it is better to use that without `.ifdef` directive.

So, please, correct me if I'm wrong,

Comment: Actually, I was wrong a little. `.ifdef` defined the MACRO with the name given in the string after `.ifdef` with its "attributes". In this case, _deny sender without HELO given_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either just delete the `.ifdef` and `.endif` directives or define `CHECK_MAIL_HELO_ISSUED = yes` somwhere logically 'before' that `deny` statement.

Comment: Thank you, anyway. Though this question isn't more actual to me, I hope this could help someone else.